# .one() jQuery function is raised multiple times automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tables:

First table saves users' answers and then let the user choose the cells from the table.
Second table reflects the cells that were choosed in the first table.

First table:

```
<table id="first_table">
  <tr>
      @foreach (var item in ViewBag.parameters)  //for example ViewBag.parameters has 3 items
      {
          <th>@item</th>
      }
  </tr>
</table>
```

For this table I add the cells("td") dynamically. Each cell has an input box for users' answers.

Second table:

```
<table id="second_table">
      @foreach (var item in ViewBag.parameters)
      {
          <tr><th>@item :</th></tr>
      }
</table>
```

Then I have a button that chooses the cells from the first table and adds them to the second table. Additionally it refreshes the second table and let the user choose the cells again from the first table:

```
$("#clear_Button").click(function (e) {
        alert("click from clear_button");

        $("#second_table td").each(function (e) {
            $(this).remove();
        }); //remove all the cells from the second table

        e.stopPropagation();

        $("#first_table td").css("border", "1px solid black");

        $("#first_table td").one('click', function (evt) {
            alert("click from .one()");
            $(this).css("border", "3px solid yellow"); //mark the clicked cell
            var id_col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this)); //index for the second table where to append the cell
            $("#second_table tr:eq(" + id_col + ")").append("<td>" +  $(this).children().val() + "</td>");
         });
    });
```

Sometimes the .one() function is raised multiple times when I clicked it once, and as a result I get duplicates added to the second table. I could not find the pattern why it does such a thing. Could you please suggest me?

Comment: I've run into similar inconsistent behavior with .one() before as well; eventually I found that calling .off() as the last step in my .one() function addressed the issue.

Comment: $(this).off(evt)? Unfortunatelly it did not solve the problem :(

Comment: Yes, or even $(this).off() with no arguments to remove all. That being said, the jQ documentation does say it only removes handlers added via jQ .on(); the documentation for .unbind() however states that it removes all attached handlers when run with no arguments. Try that & maybe also validate you're running jQ 1.7+

Comment: @Stevangelista When the $("#first_table td").one() function is called, the .one() binds to every td in the table and watches if the event is raised or not? So when I click the refresh button it still has a previous .one() function + the current .one()? I think now I found the problem:) Could you please tell me, how to erase the previous .one() functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My changes:

- changed `.one` to `.bind`
- added `.unbind` in the one-function to unbind the event-listener for the clicked cell
- added `.unbind` at the start of the click-function, to remove any old event-listeners

**JavaScript**

```
$("#clear_Button").click(function (e) {
    $("#first_table td").unbind(); //remove all existing event-listeners for all cells

    $("#second_table td").each(function (e) {
        $(this).remove(); //remove all the cells from the second table
    });
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#first_table td").css("border", "1px solid black");

    $("#first_table td").bind('click', function (evt) {
        $(this).unbind(); //remove the event-listener for the clicked cell
        $(this).css("border", "3px solid yellow"); //mark the clicked cell
        var id_col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this)); //index for the second table where to append the cell
        $("#second_table tr:eq(" + id_col + ")").append("<td>" +  $(this).children().val() + "</td>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, now I understand the problem thank you. But I need .one() function to be inside the click function. Because after clicking the clear button I just refresh the table and want to start again clicking the same cells. If .one() is out of the function, it is not clickable again(after the clear button is clicked). Is it possible to unbind previous .one() functions that were not clicked?

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov - I edited my answer, try if that works (I changed `.one` to `.bind`, was there a particular reason you used `.one`? If it works, let me know, then I'll remove my first answer

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much:) I used .one() only to let the user click on the cell only once. One more thing I learnt about jQuery, thanks:)